# Google maps API - get my custom map

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-engine

I was searching in Google APIs a way to download my map (google.com/mymaps). By downloading a map I mean POIs. I found nothing except the Google mapsengine api, but there are 2 problems:

- map id of my map is not suitable for mapsengine api - https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/reference/v1/maps/getPublished returns 404
- maps creation in maps engine is not so easy as it is in my maps.

The problem is my client wants an Android App that shows map he created before. And he wants to create it using google my maps.

Question is there any API that allows me to download that data? Or if there is not - what is the best way to fetch that map? 
The only idea that comes to my mind is to download map KML file, but I'd prefer to use REST api if possible.

Comment: There is no API, but you can display data from  a MyMap via the dynamic KML feed on a Google Maps Javascript API v3 map.

Comment: Related question [Creating simple Google maps with multiple markers to website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46954639/creating-simple-google-maps-with-multiple-markers-to-website)

Comment: Related question [Render a My Maps using Google Maps JavaScript API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36533307/render-a-my-maps-using-google-maps-javascript-api)

Comment: Related question [Importing myMaps data in google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32484814/importing-mymaps-data-in-google-maps)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no API for Google MyMaps at this time.  Vote up this [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2953) if you want to see it happen.