# Importing myMaps data in google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm developing a web/mobile application that processes itineraries to deliver added value to the existing mapping applications. 
I'm wondering if there is a way to import data from google's myMaps (the points A, B, C, etc.. as well as the routes... or just the points minimally). If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to export the KML from Google myMaps (either as a network link or directly), then display that using the Google Maps Javascript API v3 [KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer)

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2oaok1x1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

  var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: "http://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?forcekml=1&mid=zNPjLbo835mE.k3TvWfqGG-AU",
    map: map
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'status_changed', function() {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = kmlLayer.getStatus();
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function showLocation(locate) {

  for (var i = 0; i < parseInt(locate.length); i++) {
    var address = locate[i];
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
      address: address
    }, addAddressToMap);
  }
}

var disp_title = '.$array1.';
var gj = 0;

function addAddressToMap(response) {
  place = response.Placemark[0];
  point = new google.maps.LatLng(place.Point.coordinates[1],
    place.Point.coordinates[0]);
  map.setCenter(point, 7);
  var marker1 = createMarker(point, disp_title[gj], response.name);
  map.addOverlay(marker1);
  gj++;
}

function createMarker(point) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    title: name
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(html + "<br />Location: " + place_name);
  });


}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="status"></div>
<div id="map_canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```