# How do use Google API so send a previously created KML file to My Google Maps, then get the returning URL to display in a web page

Tags: api, kml

Here is the code I am using to display the KML file :

```
 <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1tIJmiNw2JxrDmSNbnoV2NGsft9Y" width="650" height="360"></iframe>
              <canvas id="cvs4" width="300px" height="190px">[No canvas support]</canvas>
```

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1tIJmiNw2JxrDmSNbnoV2NGsft9Y" width="650" height="360"></iframe>
<canvas id="cvs4" width="300px" height="190px">[No canvas support]</canvas>
```

But I don't have a method of uploading the KML file

Answer (score 1):

related questions:

- [Importing myMaps data in google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32484814/importing-mymaps-data-in-google-maps)
- [My google places kml url javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713611/my-google-places-kml-url-javascript)

Use the `mid` information in a URL like this:

`http://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?forcekml=1&mid=1tIJmiNw2JxrDmSNbnoV2NGsft9Y`

to access it as KML.

You can see it on a Google Maps Javascript API v3 map like this:

```js
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

  var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    // your URL: https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1tIJmiNw2JxrDmSNbnoV2NGsft9Y
    url: "http://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?forcekml=1&mid=1tIJmiNw2JxrDmSNbnoV2NGsft9Y",
    map: map
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'status_changed', function() {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = kmlLayer.getStatus();
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="status"></div>
<div id="map_canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

Comment: Many thanks for the code snippet, I'm still struggling for the logic on how to upload a local KML file to MyMaps using Google API, all reference refers to manual imports. My KML files are dynamically created based on completing a form , so it so much displaying in a APP , its how I transfer ?

Comment: If you have the KML file, why do you need to upload it to MyMaps, serve it from a public server.

Comment: Thanks , sounds logical to me, but reading a few posts it seems my server will have to be open, given that I have the KML sitting on web server can you provide a sample code on how I would access it and render , in the format of <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1tIJmiNw2JxrDmSNbnoV2NGsft9Y" width="650" height="360"></iframe>
              <canvas id="cvs4" width="300px" height="190px">[No canvas support]</canvas>

Comment: You would need to use the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

Comment: Thought this might solve the problem , but have read Google does now not support this type of calls, any thoughts. Have made the KML file public access :http://maps.google.com/maps?q=https://www.dropbox.com/s/kgpbcqdnpgqpr2q/Fraud_Google_API_MAP.kml?dl=0"

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Google does now not support this type of calls".  Google definitely supports [KmlLayer](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kml)