# Google API for retrieving markers from an existing Google Map

Tags: javascript, rest, google-maps, google-cloud-platform, google-maps-markers

Browsing through all the API:s in the Google Cloud catalog, I can't figure out if any of them are capable of returning a list of markers from an existing map created with Google Maps.

One of my clients created [the following map](https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=123NHZo7-vcfBAhYpF_YWbrgEpMQ&ll=60.39102084711883%2C16.44316115000003&z=5), and since this looks awful simply embedding on their website, I instead want to use the Maps JavaScript API to create a custom map, with all these markers.

Do I need to setup all these markers again in a way that I can actually loop through and add them all to the map, or is there *any* way for me to call a REST API using the ID from their existing map to avoid this double work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a "MyMap". You can load them as KML on a `KmlLayer` with the `mid=123NHZo7-vcfBAhYpF_YWbrgEpMQ`, like this: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/3o7Lv216/),

```
  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'https://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?mid=123NHZo7-vcfBAhYpF_YWbrgEpMQ',
    map: map
  });
```

[image]

Related questions:

- [My google places kml url javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713611/my-google-places-kml-url-javascript)
- [Importing myMaps data in google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32484814/importing-mymaps-data-in-google-maps)
- [Render a My Maps using Google Maps JavaScript API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36533307/render-a-my-maps-using-google-maps-javascript-api)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 11,
    center: {
      lat: 41.876,
      lng: -87.624
    }
  });

  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'https://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?mid=123NHZo7-vcfBAhYpF_YWbrgEpMQ',
    map: map
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- add your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk">
</script>
```