# How to add marker of a coordinate to a Custom (my places) map?

Tags: google-maps, web-applications

I have a custom map I created by adding lots of location markers. These are 
 the branch locations.

Next, I have created an excel file where the user can enter a customer location and a link will be created that opens the above custom map. Right now it centers on the customer location, but doesn't show a marker. The url looks something like this:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=**mycustommap**-&hl=en&ll=22.9860302%2C-11.2430203&z=15
```

The lat/long are the coordinates I would like to mark on the custom map.

How do I add a marker with those coordinates to my custom (my places) map?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the "Exported KML" from your custom My Maps map to render the data on a [Google Maps Javascript API v3 KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer).  Then add your marker to it, the normal [Google Maps Javascript API v3 way](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple).  You would have to host your map somewhere and process the query string for the coordinates to load the marker.

Most of the example is from this related question: [Render a My Maps using Google Maps JavaScript API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36533307/render-a-my-maps-using-google-maps-javascript-api), with the exception of the marker code.

**code snippet:** (data from [this MyMap](https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=1-mpfnFjp1e5JJ1YkSBjE6ZX_d9w&usp=sharing))

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

  var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: "http://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?mid=zNPjLbo835mE.k3TvWfqGG-AU",
    map: map
  });
  // Add a marker
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(32.735316, -117.149046),
    title: "My Marker"
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```