# How to download a KML file from Google Maps API via "mid" param?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I am doing an application where I want to download a KML file of a Google Maps referenced by a "mid" parameter, like [this](https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=1Mdlz2iXu_iZCPhUhzKvT2B2j-6E): `https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=1Mdlz2iXu_iZCPhUhzKvT2B2j-6E`

I can download it manually clicking in the "three dots button" > "Download KML file"but I want to automatize this process.

Is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `http://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?forcekml=1&mid=` before the unique identifier:

http://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?forcekml=1&mid=1Mdlz2iXu_iZCPhUhzKvT2B2j-6E

(Related question:
[Render a My Maps using Google Maps JavaScript API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36533307/render-a-my-maps-using-google-maps-javascript-api))

**code snippet displaying that KML on a map:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 11,
    center: {
      lat: 41.876,
      lng: -87.624
    }
  });

  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?forcekml=1&mid=1Mdlz2iXu_iZCPhUhzKvT2B2j-6E',
    map: map
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a Google My Map (not Google Maps API).

This will give you the KMZ version (compressed):

```
https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/kml?mid=1Mdlz2iXu_iZCPhUhzKvT2B2j-6E
```

This will give you the KML version (uncompressed, does not support all icons):

```
https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/kml?mid=1Mdlz2iXu_iZCPhUhzKvT2B2j-6E&forcekml=1
```

This will give you a networklink in KMZ:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/kml?mid=1Mdlz2iXu_iZCPhUhzKvT2B2j-6E&nl=1
```

And this will give you a networklink in KML:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/kml?mid=1Mdlz2iXu_iZCPhUhzKvT2B2j-6E&nl=1&forcekml=1
```

Comment: Do you happen to know how/if it is possible to access a KML file from Google My Maps using https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/kml?mid=1Mdlz2iXu_iZCPhUhzKvT2B2j-6E&forcekml=1 using javascript on a cross-domain server?  I want to be able to parse the kml file.  I have tried but get blocked by CORS.  Know of any reliable work-arounds?

Comment: Is there a list of all the options for the URL parameters?  I'm trying to see if the "forcekml" can be done to only export a given layer of the map, not the whole map.