# Access data of an map created on google my map through API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i'm not sure if this question may related to this one: [Google maps API - get my custom map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27177421/google-maps-api-get-my-custom-map)

What i want to do is to read data from a map i created with google my maps (google.com/mymaps) and with data i mean the map-name, the layer-names, the layers, drawn polygons (preferrable as an array of points), POI, etc.

Now what i have found is that you can export the map as an .KML-File and use it to display it with help of google map APIs. But what i need is not only to display it, but read data associated with them, for example the given descriptions, the coordiantes of a point, the names, etc.

I have found no information if this is possible with help of the google map api. Or if i have to parse this from the .xml with help of an XMLParser.

An example map i created is this one: https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=1AaUB-Ap83t_SiiGYwVuV3449ySY

I'm also interested if it is possible to read data from the map without exporting it and accessing it "live".

Platforms i want to use are Android & iOS.

Regards

Comment: Well, I think if this is a custom map created by you, there is no way to get its details like coordinates because you are not connected thru the Google API. So if you really want to get the details of the maps, I suggest you to use the [Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/).

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by following the next steps:

1. Click on 3 dots from the burger menu and select the option "Download KML"
2. Open the file and access the link from CDATA

   `<href><![CDATA[https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/3/kml?forcekml=1&mid=xxxxxxxx]]></href>`
3. Open the new downloaded file and you will see that each item is inside an Placemark

```
    <Placemark>
            <name>Late Ginger Beetle</name>
            <styleUrl>#icon-1899-FF5252-nodesc</styleUrl>
            <Point>
              <coordinates>
                20.0191825,40.4207996,0
              </coordinates>
            </Point>
          </Placemark>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question sounds like a feature request posted in the public issue tracker:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2953

As I can see, currently this feature is not implemented in API. There is no timeline in the public issue tracker. You can star the feature request to express your interest and receive future updates from Google.